# Medias not showing in wordpress backoffice

Tags: wordpress, media

can someone help me please ?

I imported some medias from another wordpress site using WP-importer
The image files are present in wp-content/uploads/2014/09 but in the wordpress media library nothing shows up.

I dont know how does wordpress handle images? is there a table in DB ?

I am using wordpress 4.0

Thanks a lot for any idea !

Comment: Can you access that images by browser? like yousite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/img.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images also stored in database wp_post table and images post type is attachment, so please check your wp_post table.